# Integrating google analytics without using xcode for ios and Android?

Tags: android, ios

I am developing a mobile app keeping in mind that I will be targeting both the iOS and Android platforms. I now wish to integrate Google Analytics into my app.

I have come across a lot of stuff that suggests using xcode and integrating the GA libraries into it(for iOS). I know it can be done this way but I don't have the Mac machine to run my app on.

> *My question is if there exists any way by which I can integrate GA into my mobile app without using XCode*.

So far, I have used the phonegap plugin into my App and I am developing and testing the app simultaneously on safari before making any deployments on server and finally testing my app on an iphone.

Kind Regards,

Ronan

Comment: I seem to have resolved this, I have just got to know I need to follow the web app way and not the pure app way, so I need not require XCode for this purpose. I am now using the simple GA script the one we use for our websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I have now developed my application so that this can be accessed like any other web application(website) instead of using it as a downloadable app, therefore, I am now using the standard async GA script which is now working perfectly for me.